# Using JQuery to reference element of HTML

Tags: jquery, html, class

I found some code using jquery to reference a div element:

```
divContainer.empty().append(
        $('<div></div>', {'class': 'pdfemb-inner-div'}) // here
        .append($('<canvas></canvas>', {'class': 'pdfemb-the-canvas'})));
```

I don't understand how **"$('', {'class': 'pdfemb-inner-div'})"** can reference the div element, any one have idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the info about jquery given by Putra Soerya, this code create a div with class attribute=pdfemb-inner-div, and then create a canvas with class attribute=pdfemb-the-canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to achieve is add a class to the 'div' you're appending. Here's an answer:

```
divContainer.empty().append(
        $('<div class='pdfemb-inner-div'></div>') // here
        .append($('<canvas class='pdfemb-the-canvas'></canvas>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied this text from official website.

please read from the official jquery website https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with ). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as explained above. But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these elements.

As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn) can be used as a property of the object passed to the second parameter

Comment: Thank you for you info. Now I understand how it works.